# Core data stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have

```
_privateManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

and

```
_mainManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
_mainManagedObjectContext.parentContext = self.privateManagedObjectContex
```

And i use always _mainManagedObjectContext, without perform block, is it right?

Comment: define `always`...

Comment: [self.mainManagedObjectContext deleteObject:object], for insert and fetch request

Comment: Depends on which thread your are using the moc. If you are using moc on the main thread, it is fine. If you are using the moc on a background thread, it isn't.

Comment: Sometimes I use background thread, but i not get a crash

Comment: If you use a MOC with a concurrency type of `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` from a different thread, it is a bug.  If you want to do it anyway, please let us know what app you are developing, so we can stay away from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` for a managed object context, you can skip `performBlock` and `performBlockAndWait` **only** if you are using the context on the main thread. If you use it on another thread, it *might* not crash or cause other problems, but only because you got lucky that time. Not using the block calls on other threads is a major threading error, and is very clearly "doing it wrong". The fact that it hasn't crashed yet doesn't change that-- you've written a time bomb into your app, and sooner or later it will explode.